# How to display all the documents from firestore to html

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

```
db.collection('Buses').get().then((snapshot) = > {
  snapshot.forEach((busDatas) = > {
    busData = busDatas.data()
    console.log(busData)

    document.getElementById('bus-container-dynamic').innerHTML = `

<div class="single-room-area d-flex align-items-center 
  mb-50 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="100ms">
  <div class="room-thumbnail">
    <img src="${busData.ImageLink}" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="room-content">

    <h2>${busData.TourName}</h2>
    <h6>${busData.From} to ${busData.To}</h6>
    <h4>₹ ${busData.SeatPrice} </h4>

    <div class="room-feature">
      <h6>Boarding Point  <span>${busData.BoardingTime}</span></h6>
      <h6>Dropping Point <span>${busData.DroppingTime}</span></h6>
      <h6>Seats Left <span>${busData.SeatsLeft}</span></h6>
      <h6>Total Time <span>${busData.TotalTime}</span></h6>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="btn view-detail-btn">
      View Details 
      <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>

    </div>

  </div>`
})})
```

I am using this code to display my code in html but the only one document is showing on the webpage , but when i print that data in console i am getting all the documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Do not overwrite the contents of the element on each iteration, append to them.

In fact, use a variable to append to, then assign that to the element, so you only have to manipulate the DOM once.

This line:

```
document.getElementById('bus-container-dynamic').innerHTML = `...`;
```

Keeps **re-writing** the whole contents of `#bus-container-dynamic` at **each** iteration.

You could instead store all the data in one variable, then assign that to the element.

A short snippet to illustrate the solution.

```js
const myData = [1,2,3,4,5];

// Create a variable here 
let html = '';

myData.forEach( e => {

  // Create your element's HTML inside the loop
  html += e;
  
});

// Then assign it to the element
document.getElementById('my-element').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="my-element"></div>
```

And this is how I would modify the code that you posted originally.

```
db.collection('Buses').get().then((snapshot) = > {

  let html = '';

  snapshot.forEach((busDatas) = > {

    busData = busDatas.data()

    console.log(busData)

    html += `

<div class="single-room-area d-flex align-items-center 
  mb-50 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="100ms">

  <div class="room-thumbnail">
    <img src="${busData.ImageLink}" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="room-content">

    <h2>${busData.TourName}</h2>
    <h6>${busData.From} to ${busData.To}</h6>
    <h4>₹ ${busData.SeatPrice} </h4>

    <div class="room-feature">
      <h6>Boarding Point  <span>${busData.BoardingTime}</span></h6>
      <h6>Dropping Point <span>${busData.DroppingTime}</span></h6>
      <h6>Seats Left <span>${busData.SeatsLeft}</span></h6>
      <h6>Total Time <span>${busData.TotalTime}</span></h6>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="btn view-detail-btn">
      View Details 
      <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>

  </div>

</div>`

  document.getElementById('bus-container-dynamic').innerHTML = html;

  })    // End foreach
})      // End then
```